# Storing Session State in an ASP.Net Web Farm (Memcachedb or...?)

Tags: asp.net, session-state, memcachedb

We have an ASP.Net [MVC] web farm (Windows Server 2008 R2 running IIS). For which we want to share session state across each box.

I'm aware that we can do this with SQL Server, but understand that there is an overhead to this (someone mentioned a 25% drop in performance).

Memcachedb keeps getting mentioned time and time again, however I can't seem to find a way to hook it into ASP.Net for the purpose of session state.

Has anyone put together a successful implementation of Memcachedb with .Net? Or are there other suggestions on the best approach to storing session state across all boxes?

Many thanks

Comment: I do not see this 25% drop performance that you say... can you tell us where did you see that ? In my sql server the session state is super fast that I can not even care about.

Comment: I can't find the source that explicitly said 25%, however this article cites '10%-25%'. 

As in some cases we use complex types I'm thinking our hit may be on the higher side: http://idunno.org/articles/277.aspx - FTA: "Using SQL is slower than using InProc session state. When storing basic data types (string, int, etc), ASP.Net can take 10%-25% longer to store their values. Complex types take even longer. Of course because you are connecting to a separate server it does use bandwidth on your network."

Comment: The 10%-25% sounds too big (but...), my sites makes 70ms-200ms to start show a page, and I use sql session state. Now the 10% on 100ms, is just 10ms extra, too small to count as delay. And my delay is not come from the session state. Now the connection to the other server using SQL is an issue if your one server is on Europe and the other on Usa you may have a 100ms+ lag., but if they are on the same building the lag is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Memcached session provider for ASP.NET on codeplex [site](http://memcachedproviders.codeplex.com/).

[AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790849.aspx) has ASP.NET session [state provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790859.aspx).

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12401/foss-asp-net-session-replication-solution) may help a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another Memcached session provider at github - 
https://github.com/rohita/MemcachedSessionProvider